# Problem with my unmute command discord.js v11.5

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with my unmute command I have make in the 11.5 version of discord.js :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

    module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
        if (!message.guild.members.get(message.author.id).hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
            return message.channel.send(":x: | Vous n'avez pas la permission");
        };

        let user = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (!user) {
            return message.channel.send(":x: | Aucune mention n'a été faite");
        };

        if (!message.guild.members.get(user.id).roles.has(message.guild.roles.get("680045212374270010"))) {
            return message.channel.send(":x: | L'utilisateur n'est pas mute")
        }

        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL)
            .setTitle("**Unmute**")
            .addField("Modérateur", message.author.username, true)
            .addField("User", user.tag, true)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL);

        message.channel.send(embed);
        message.guild.members.get(user.id).removeRole(message.guild.roles.get("680045212374270010"));

    };

    module.exports.help = {
        name: "unmute"
    };
```

That work but, the user I have mentionned have the role Muted and it send the user doesn't have the role Muted and the role was remove. Why ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first();

if(!member.roles.find(role => role.id === "680045212374270010")) {
     //do something
}
```

You'll get the member from the first mention by `message.mentions.members.first()`.
Then you'll find the role in the member's role collection and check if it's null or not. If it's null, the code in `//do something` will run.
It's way cleaner like this, isn't it?